# Struts2 nested iteration through Lists using dynamic variables

Tags: java, list, loops, struts2, ognl

I'm iterating through a `List<SomeObject>`, but I want only to print out certain attributes of `SomeObject` depending on the attributes specified in another `List`. So far, I have got it. What I'm not sure, how to use the item in the `List` as the attribute of `SomeObject` that I want to print out.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="theList" var="listItem" status="theListCount">
    <s:iterator value="listOfAttributes" var="attr" status="attrListCount">
        Attribute=<s:property value="#attr"/> Value=<s:property value='#listItem.[%{#attr}]'/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: It's not adequate name for the attributes of the object. You should check OGNL syntax of your expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `#attr` is a reserved keyword, so don't use it as a variable value. And use `[]` notation to reference property of the object.

```jsp
<s:iterator value="theList" var="listItem" status="theListCount">
  <s:iterator value="listOfAttributes" var="atrbt" status="attrListCount">
      Attribute=<s:property value="#atrbt"/> Value=<s:property value="#listItem[#atrbt]"/>
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to force OGNL in the part of the expression

```jsp
<s:iterator value="theList" var="listItem" status="theListCount">
    <s:iterator value="listOfAttributes" var="atr" status="attrListCount">
        Attribute=<s:property value="#atr"/> Value=<s:property value="#listItem[#atr]"/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```